# Allow only letters and spaces - jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am validating a text field to allow only letters and spaces.

This is the method I am using:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter only letters");
```

But the regular expression is not allowing spaces between words.

I tried : 
`/^[a-z ]+$/i.test(value)` and `/^[a-z\s]+$/i.test(value)`

jQuery version - `1.7.1`

Answer (score 9):

The regular expression is:

```
^[a-z\s]*$
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4fcH/1/)

Comment: do you need the `|` when they are in a character class? i thought that was the point of the character class.

Comment: A problem with expressions like this is that `[]` classes not necessarily imply that all characters are actually used. For example, the above will accept a string consisting of 100 newlines. I'm not sure this is what OP really meant.

Comment: @thg435. Though you're right, this is was the OP really asked for... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(value);
},"Please enter only letters");
```

replace this : **`/^[a-z\s]+$/i`**

by this :**`/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/`**

I checked It works.